# TypeError: unsupported operand type. How to to find the smallest difference between numbers in a list

Tags: python, typeerror

i need to find the smallest difference between numbers in a list.

For some reason it doesnt work when i input numbers in the console, and i get this error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`

```
def najmanja_razlika(): #smallest_diff
    a=input('unesite brojeve liste')
    b=len(a)
    razlika=10**20 #difference
        for i in range(b-1):
            for j in range(i+1,b):
                if int(abs(a[i]-a[j]))<razlika:
                razlika=abs(a[i]-a[j])
        return razlika
print(str(najmanja_razlika()))
```

What i get when i run this is:

unesite brojeve liste5,4,9,3

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Nina/PycharmProjects/klkOR/klk4.py", line 19, in <module>
    print(str(najmanja_razlika()))
  File "C:/Users/Nina/PycharmProjects/klkOR/klk4.py", line 11, in najmanja_razlika
    if int(abs(a[i]-a[j]))<razlika:


TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not convert the string input into an int or float, you might like to do something like this.

```
def najmanja_razlika(): #smallest_diff
    a=[int(i) for i in input('unesite brojeve liste').split(',')]
    b=len(a)
    razlika=10**20 #difference
    for i in range(b-1):
        for j in range(i+1,b):
            if int(abs(a[i]-a[j]))<razlika:
                razlika=abs(a[i]-a[j])
    return razlika
print(str(najmanja_razlika()))
```

Also, note that indentation matters in Python.

This is the output that I obtained:

```
unesite brojeve liste5,4,2,9,6
1
```

By the way, if you sort your vector first, you reduce the complexity from O(n^2) to O(nlogn).

Comment: It still doesnt work and i made the changes suggested, i got:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5,4,2,9,6  @siong

Comment: did you include the .split() at the end?

Comment: I did, i still got the same error. if you know a different way to do this it would also help @Siong

Comment: just checking, when you input your data, do you separate each number by a single space? or do you use a comma? I was assuming that you were using a space.

Comment: i changed it to .split(',') and i was using a comma @Siong

Comment: I tried and my code works on my system without any error message.

Comment: And what did you get as a result? i mean, was it correct?

Comment: I have included my output, 5-4=1 so it returns 1. You can also run my code [here](http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user46_wiQgm5HL6z_0.py). it doesn't give an error for your input.

Comment: for whatever reason i was getting just a zero, but its working now :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have `numpy` installed you could use it to efficiently compute the minimum difference (it is always faster than pure Python loops). I would also use `json` (part of the standard library, no need to install it) to parse the input string.

```py
import json
import numpy as np

def min_difference():
    input_string = '[' + input('Enter comma-separated numbers: ') + ']'
    a = np.array(json.loads(input_string))
    mask = ~np.eye(a.shape[0], dtype=bool)
    return np.abs(a[:, None] - a[None, :])[mask].min()
```